# how to remove white space at the beginning and end of a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, replace

I create a javascript parser for my markup language.
I wish no spaces between tags and content like this:

```
__underline a sentence __and more. 
(or correctly : __underline a sentence__ and more.)
```

to :

```
<u>underline a sentence</u> and more.
```

But result is in the first case :

```
<u>underline a sentence </u>and more.
```

My code :

```
var tabML = ['\'','*','_'],
    tabHTML = ['em','strong','u']
    tag, char;
for(var i=0; i<tabML.length; i++){
    tag = tabHTML[i]; char = tabML[i];
    regex = new RegExp(char+char+'(.+)'+char+char, 'ig');
    txt = txt.replace(regex, '<'+tag+'>$1</'+tag+'>');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with `<u>$1</u>`

```
__\s*(.*?)\s*__\s*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/4)

```
> var s1 = "__underline a sentence __and more."
undefined
> var s2 = "__underline a sentence__ and more."
undefined
> s1.replace(/__\s*(.*?)\s*__\s*/g, '<u>$1</u> ')
'<u>underline a sentence</u> and more.'
> s2.replace(/__\s*(.*?)\s*__\s*/g, '<u>$1</u> ')
'<u>underline a sentence</u> and more.'
```

Comment: Thanks. Just add \s* after 2 first underscores : __\s*(.*?)\s*__\s*

Answer (score 0):

```
__(.*?)[ ]*__[ ]*
```

Try this.Replace by `<u>$1</u>`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/5

```
var re = /__(.*?)[ ]*__[ ]*/gm;
var str = '__underline a sentence __and more.\n__underline a sentence__ and more.';
var subst = '<u>$1</u> ';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```